# Login and password in Safari private mode

Tags: safari, password

Is it possible to auto-fill or save passwords for certain sites in Safari private mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving passwords is disabled in Private Browsing.

AutoFill is not automatic, but you can AutoFill manually:

- iOS: focus on the username or password field and tap ‘AutoFill Password’ above the keyboard.
- macOS: Edit → AutoFill Form (⇧⌘A)

Comment: what about macOS?

Comment: @codddeer123 Yes, see edit

Comment: Is there a way to enable saving passwords in Private Browsing?